# Change color of augmented Object (AR Core) at runtime

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am using the Image Target Detection example from AR Core SDK. I want to change the color of the object at runtime through script. A material is attached to that object.

```
// Create an anchor to ensure that ARCore keeps tracking this augmented image.
Anchor anchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
visualizer = (AugmentedImageVisualizer)Instantiate(
AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab, anchor.transform);
visualizer.Image = image;
m_Visualizers.Add(image.DatabaseIndex, visualizer);
Renderer rend = visualizer.GetComponent<Renderer>();
rend.sharedMaterial.shader = Shader.Find("BaseColor");
Color red = new Color(255,0,0);
rend.sharedMaterial.SetColor("_Color", red);
```

This is my current code which I have tried to implement after taking hint from different answers but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I can do that by creating a Material that has the respective color and by giving the AR object a component of this type (obviously you need to assign the references to `renderer` and `colorMaterial` in the inspector):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ARObjectController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Renderer renderer;
    public Material colorMaterial;

    public SetMaterial()
    {
        renderer.material = colorMaterial;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the model which we are trying to use has so many child ojects , its a machine and has many parts, same material color is applied to half of the parts, is there any way to change the color of the matrial which is applied to all those parts and color of all the parts is changed?

Comment: Looks like it's possible: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html; haven't tested it though

Comment: yeah this doesn't work. It works with a normal object but not working with augmented object.

Comment: You could still create materials for every color you need, though.

Comment: Do you still have any doubts about this? Otherwise could you please tag my answer as solution?